# Nagios Make Error

Tags: nagios

I'm having an issue with installing a nagios server. I'm not linux genius but I know a bit of the basics but I wasn't really sure where to go from here.

I think I've got all the dependencies installed and setup everything else and the configuration seems to go fine(i've been following the guide in Nagios (2nd edition) by W Barth) it's just when I run "make all" it errors out.

I'm running CentOS 6.4 minimal install.

Here's the error

```
cd ./base && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/nagios/base'
gcc -Wall -g -O2  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DNSCORE   -c -o checks.o checks.c
In file included from checks.c:41:
../include/epn_nagios.h:11:20: error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory
../include/epn_nagios.h:12:18: error: perl.h: No such file or directory
In file included from checks.c:41:
../include/epn_nagios.h:31: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’
checks.c: In function ‘run_async_service_check’:
checks.c:355: error: ‘SV’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:355: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
checks.c:355: error: for each function it appears in.)
checks.c:355: error: ‘plugin_hndlr_cr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:361: error: ‘dSP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:557: error: ‘ENTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:558: error: ‘SAVETMPS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:559: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PUSHMARK’
checks.c:559: error: ‘SP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:560: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XPUSHs’
checks.c:560: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sv_2mortal’
checks.c:560: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘newSVpv’
checks.c:564: error: ‘PUTBACK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:568: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘call_pv’
checks.c:568: error: ‘G_SCALAR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:568: error: ‘G_EVAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:570: error: ‘SPAGAIN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:572: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SvTRUE’
checks.c:572: error: ‘ERRSV’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:581: error: ‘POPs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:584: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SvPVX’
checks.c:629: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘newSVsv’
checks.c:634: error: ‘FREETMPS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:635: error: ‘LEAVE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:713: error: ‘G_ARRAY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:717: error: ‘POPpx’ undeclared (first use in this function)
checks.c:718: error: ‘POPi’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[1]: *** [checks.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/nagios/base'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Found which package I was missing

```
perl-ExtUtils-Embed
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use packages from Repoforge or EPEL?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `perl-devel` package. Run this command:

```
yum install perl-devel
```

This should do it.

Comment: Hey, I've just installed perl-devel (it was missing) but I'm still getting the same error. Perl was already installed but are there any other perl dependencies or development packages I could have missed?

Comment: `syslinux-devel` could be the missing part. Install it and check...

Comment: Nope still getting the error. I've just removed the embedded perl interpreter from my nagios install config and its installed fine. I really want the embedded perl interpreter though. I could probably live without though.

Comment: check this:

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29689524